# Career Advice Model Documentation Role (What is it exactly? and transition to wider quant role in future, can't find info online)

Tags: models, quants

first timer here,I received an 'inmail' on linkedin from a recruiter regarding a role in model documentation team as part of the quantitative modeling and analytics department of a 'global bank'. The exact bank wasn't stated hence couldn't find more info online. I am personally interested in the general quant finance space(quant trading, quant portfolio management, quant analysis).My dilemma is ,could I transition from a model "documenter" to  a wider quant role?. I couldn't find any information online regarding this particular job role , model documentation(actually my first time hearing of it).If anyone knows about this role in general , kindly pass on some info.

A bit of context on my background.Bsc.Actuarial Science,Msc.Mathematical Modelling, Equity research for a year(in Africa,emerging market),
Data science Associate , planning to take CFA and FRM(soon as I can afford it)

Comment: Check the linked answer for some stories on how to become a quant. The book by Mark Joshi I link to in that answer explicitly discusses your dilemma.

Comment: I must stress this is entirely self-promotional. I see you're a student in Ireland, do check out the [European Quant Awards](https://www.cfasociety.org/ireland/Pages/Quant-Awards-2020.aspx) organized by the Irish, French, Spanish and Dutch CFA societies where you can win a cash prize and a registration fee to the CFA with your thesis.

Comment: Note that other career advice questions are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: I have read Joshi's paper and it doesn't address my question. I'm confused because model documentation isn't a stereotypical career path ( that I haven't heard of and is not addressed in Joshi's book) that is why I ask this question.I guess Im asking if its generally an entry role or not and what is the career progression from that particular path.

Comment: That's subjective that's why these questions are considered off-topic. My 2 cents: 1) I'd say it's a form of model validation but the furthest from the action 2) Model validation is already from the action, see Mark Joshi's document 3) Doing this full time will get boring fast. Of course you can transition but that's possible from anywhere.

Comment: As far as I know there shouldn't be a narrowly defined "Model Documentation" role in a big investment bank. If I were you, I would ask for further details on the position.

Comment: I’ve voted to close because this question isn’t appropriate here, maybe try asking on quantnet? Also, seems like the group is part of the model review team of the bank